# Запустить и экспортировать карту-файл для майнкрафта из внутренних ресурсов

Tags: java, android

я хочу экспортировать и запустить файл из папки assets в игру.
вот как я это делаю, но это не работает:
манифест:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   

     package="com.worldmaps.testingformaps">
    
    
    
        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <provider
                android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
                android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
                android:exported="false"
                android:grantUriPermissions="true">
                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                    android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
            </provider>
    
        </application>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    </manifest>
```

активити которая экспортирует:

```
package com.worldmaps.testingformaps;

        import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
        import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
        import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

        import android.Manifest;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
        import android.net.Uri;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.os.Environment;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        import java.io.BufferedWriter;
        import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
        import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
        import java.io.File;
        import java.io.FileInputStream;
        import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
        import java.io.FileOutputStream;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.io.InputStream;
        import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final static String fileName = "1.mcworld";
    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_WRITE = 1001;
    private boolean permissionGranted;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button buton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        buton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!permissionGranted){
            checkPermissions();
            return;
        }
                File f = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Minecraft/Maps/");
                if (!f.exists()){
                    f.mkdirs();
                }
        FileOutputStream fos = null;

        try {

            InputStream ims = getAssets().open("1.mcworld");
            fos = new FileOutputStream(new File( f.getPath()+fileName));
            if (!new File( f.getPath()+fileName).exists()) {
                fos.write(readBytes(ims));
            }
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File( f.getPath()+fileName));
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndTypeAndNormalize(uri, "application/minecraft");
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            pre(" хранилище");
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {


        }
        finally{
            try{
                if(fos!=null)
                    fos.close();
            }
            catch(IOException ex){


            }
        }

        

            }
        });
    }



    public boolean isExternalStorageWriteable(){
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        return  Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state);
    }

    public boolean isExternalStorageReadable(){
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        return  (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) ||
                Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state));
    }

    private boolean checkPermissions(){

        if(!isExternalStorageReadable() || !isExternalStorageWriteable()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Внешнее хранилище не доступно", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        }
        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if(permissionCheck!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_PERMISSION_WRITE);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults){
        switch (requestCode){
            case REQUEST_PERMISSION_WRITE:
                if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    permissionGranted = true;
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Разрешения получены", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Необходимо дать разрешения", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    public void pre(String t){
        Toast.makeText(this, " доступно" +t, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public byte[] readBytes(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        // this dynamically extends to take the bytes you read
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        // this is storage overwritten on each iteration with bytes
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        // we need to know how may bytes were read to write them to the byteBuffer
        int len = 0;
        while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }

        // and then we can return your byte array.
        return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
    }


}
```

провайдер:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <root-path name="root" path="." />
</paths>
```

Comment: `f.getPath()` даёт путь без слэша в конце, не зависимо папка это или файл. Нужно либо добавить этот слэш между папкой и файлом, либо использовать другой конструктор: `new File( f, fileName)`. Так же `uri` для отправки в другое приложение нужно создавать методом [`FileProvider.getUriForFile(Context context, String authority, File file)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider#getUriForFile(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File)) вместо `Uri.fromFile(...)` так как схема `file://` запрещена (не помню с какой версии системы).